# How do I load an ecosystem map into R

Tags: r, sf

I'm new to GIS, but proficient in R, and I would like to load the ecosystem map of Europe into R, to check overlap of my own shapefiles with the ecosystem types in this map.
[This](https://sdi.eea.europa.eu/data/7c0cf3f2-ab54-4cd0-a635-b322df7197f6) is the link to the map files.
Which file with which command do I use to use it in R? I cannot get it to work

Comment: Load file -> set symbology -> create a map. The link you posted has many layers, not a single map. So you need to reproduce the symbology that the PDF file indicates. This can't be addressed by a single answer here, so you need to figure it out how to load .lyr and .tif first

Comment: What couldn't you get to work? Have a read of https://r.geocompx.org/ if you want somewhere to start.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Geotiffs. Their file-ending is .tif

Then you can do:

```
# libraries
library(terra)
library(sf)

# load the data
raster_data <- rast("path/to/your/raster.tif")
shapefile_data <- st_read("path/to/your/shapefile.shp")

# vizualize the data
plot(raster_data)
plot(shapefile_data, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: When I load the .tif file from the link with rast(), I can indeed use it. But I think this is only 1 layer of many. I don't get why other layers are apparently in another format? And how do I load them?
Also, I would like to find which of my points of my sf are on which ecosystem type, so I'd like to do something like st_intersection(), only this doesn't work for a spatraster. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Your raster has pixel values 11-59. These corespond with an ecosystem type. So all ecosystems are in the same layer. The .tiv.vat holds this information.